# WordPress SQL that updates custom post type meta values (older than 6 months)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type (artwork). I need to update all (artwork) older than 6 months with a `meta_key` (status) and `meta_value` of (available) and change to (not available) in addition to updating another two `meta_key` values in that process.

So the for the first part I can return all 'available' 'artwork' older than 6 months using the following;

```
SELECT * FROM `wp207_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp207_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wm.`meta_key`='status' AND wm.`meta_value`='available')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 182
```

With these I need to `UPDATE` the following `meta_key` values;

1. Update 'status' from 'available' to 'not available'
2. Update 'price' so that value is removed (ie remove the price value if it exists)
3. Update 'price_range' so that value is removed (ie remove the price_range value if it exists)

The following SQL allows me to update 'status' from 'available' to 'not available

```
UPDATE `wp207_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp207_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wm.`meta_key`='status' AND wm.`meta_value`='available')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 182
SET `meta_value`=replace(meta_value, '0', '1')
WHERE `meta_key`='status';
```

How would I go about removing a value for a `meta_key` (see 2 and 3 above) using same query - artwork older than 6 months? For example, if I wanted to remove the price from all artwork older than 6 months, would this be the best approach?

```
UPDATE `wp207_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp207_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wm.`meta_key`='status' AND wm.`meta_value`='1')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 182
SET `meta_value`=''
WHERE `meta_key`='price';
```

I can confirm that all the `UPDATE` scripts on this post do what I needed them to do - though suspect there is a much better way.

---

**Final SQL**

```
UPDATE wp207_postmeta wm 
JOIN wp207_posts wp ON wm.post_id = wp.ID 
SET wm.meta_value='not available' 
WHERE
    wm.meta_key='status' AND
    wm.meta_value='available' AND
    post_type='artwork' AND
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), wp.post_date) > 182;

UPDATE wp207_postmeta
WHERE 
    wp207_postmeta.meta_key IN ('price', 'price_range') AND 
    wp207_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp207_posts wp WHERE 
    post_type='artwork' AND
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), wp.post_date) > 182);
```

Thank you.

Comment: If I assume that the question is "will someone write the SQL for me?", have you already tried anything?

Comment: I have the SELECT returning what I need to UPDATE but am not sure how to go about the UPDATE with INNER JOIN or how it fits in..

Comment: What's the problem with the update that you have? Does it produce an error? If so please include it. Does it update the wrong rows?

Comment: I have been able to UPDATE meta_key from one value to another. How do I query meta_keys with a value and if there is a value then remove it. So for example I want to remove the price from all artworks older than 6 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
UPDATE wp207_postmeta wm 
JOIN wp207_posts wp ON wm.post_id = wp.ID 
SET wm.meta_value='not available' 
WHERE 
    wm.meta_key='status' AND
    wm.meta_value='available' AND
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), wp.post_date) > 182;


DELETE FROM wp207_postmeta
WHERE 
    wp207_postmeta.meta_key IN ('price', 'price_range') AND 
    wp207_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp207_posts wp WHERE 
     DATEDIFF(NOW(), wp.post_date) > 182);
```

Comment: Thanks for this it looks good, though is missing the custom post type 'artwork' aspect. The other concern is with the DELETE part - it seems to me like it is deleting the meta_key and meta_value. To verify I don't want to delete the meta_key (price and price_range) - however, I do want to remove any values for these meta_keys where the custom post type is 'artwork' and has a publish date greater than 6 months from today.

Comment: In that case you can use an `UPDATE` and add additional conditions to the WHERE clause.